# Acer Aspire one d270 black screen of death bios update

Tags: bios, display

So the same issue with acer netbooks got me too, the black screen. I tried to flash the bios using various tutorials on the net, [like this one](http://lowendguru.com/2010/02/how-to-fix-the-acer-aspire-one-black-screen/). But it doesn't seem to work for me, the system never gets rebooted. I think it may be because of the incompatibility of the bios version suggested with my netbook. So I tried to get the latest bios version for my netbook. But the BIOS provided by acer, no longer contains an .fd file and a Flashit.exe, it contains only an exe file, and I don't know how I can update the BIOS with that. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Wise, Did you fix it already?

Comment: @eiefai Hi, Yes... It wasn't a BIOS problem after all. It was due to RAM failure and the part had to be replaced. Apparently, the only acer models with the black screen of death, are the two that are mentioned in Acer's FAQ page whose BIOS files for flashing are available. I mistakenly thought my model had the same issue.